# Calculating capacitance in a MOS capacitor

Tags: mosfet, nmos, solid-state-devices

> A \$MOS\$ capacitor with \$t_{ox}=10nm\$ has an \$n^{+}\$ polysilicon gate electrode and an \$n\$-type substrate with doping concentration \$ N_D=10^{15}/cm^3\$ . Given: \$V_T=kT/q=26mV\$, \$\epsilon_s = 10^{-12} F/cm\$ ,\$\epsilon_{ox} = \epsilon_s /3\$, oxide and interface are free of any charges.
> Calculate the gate-substrate capacitance at \$V_{GB} = 1 V \$ at a high measurement frequency(\$\approx 1MHz \$) in \$nF/cm^2\$.

My approach:
$$C_{ox}=\frac{\epsilon_{ox}}{t_{ox}}=333.33 nF/cm^2$$

$$V_{GB}=\Psi_s+\Psi_{ox}=\Psi_s+\frac{\sqrt{2qN_D \epsilon_s \Psi_s}}{C_{ox}}$$

$$\implies \Psi_s=0.9477V$$

$$W=\sqrt{\frac{2 \epsilon_s \Psi_s}{qN_D}}=0.00010884 cm$$

$$\implies C_s=\frac{\epsilon_s}{W}=9.1875 nF/cm^2$$

$$\implies C=\frac{C_{ox} C_s}{C_{ox}+C_s}=8.941 nF/cm^2$$

but this answer is apparently incorrect. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: https://www.chu.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Chenming-Hu_ch5-1.pdf

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75Thank you for sharing the link. I have read through an equivalent study material provided to us by our university already. However, I am unable to find out my mistake with the above equations. Could you please point out my mistake?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/594815/mos-capacitor-why-is-the-total-capacitance-just-the-oxide-capacitance-c-ox?rq=1